# Want to Upload and download files to Google Bucket Using OAuth Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a code to upload and download files to google bucket using service account credentials. But i want to do it using OAuth Credentials i.e client_id and client_secret. My current code works using service account credentials.  Here is my current code

```
service_account_info={
"type": "service_account",
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\xxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "XXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
}

from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials,project="")
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
blob = bucket.blob('testfolder/myfile.csv')
blob.upload_from_filename('d:/myfile.csv')
```

Can anyone provide a code snippet to upload using OAuth Credentials
client_id=XXX
client_secret=XXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Python Client Library has a working example of this (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python). Please do some research first before asking someone to tell you how to do it.

Comment: This requires manual browser authentication. Is there any way by which it will directly get the token and access it?

Comment: @ShakirShakeel - OAuth credentials created from User Credentials (Google Accounts, G Suite, etc) require a web browser for the user to grant access. This is part of Google's OAuth security protocol. You cannot bypass this. Use Service Accounts when you do not require user interaction. There are other types of OAuth that do allow this such as the password grant type. Google however does not support theses OAuth grant types. For the different types of OAuth authorization, review the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone provide a code snippet to upload using OAuth Credentials client_id=XXX client_secret=XXX?

As mentioned by Christian Kovanen, the Google Python Client Library has a working example of this that you can see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python).

Nonetheless, let me give you some further information regarding authentication in Google Cloud Storage, so you could decide which one fit your needs best.

#### Cloud Storage Authentication

Most of the operations you perform in Cloud Storage must be authenticated. The only exceptions are operations on objects that allow anonymous access. Objects are anonymously accessible if the `allUsers` group has READ permission, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication).

#### Ways to use Google Cloud Storage

Cloud Storage uses **OAuth 2.0** for API authentication and authorization, as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-flows).

Theere are various types of authentication depending on how you would like to access Google Cloud Storage, but if fall into two general types:

- **A server-centric flow** allows the application to directly hold the credentials of a service account. You could use the default service account, or create a new one [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account).
- **A user-centric flow** allows an application to obtain credentials from an end user. In your specific case, this is the type of authentication **you are looking for**. The user must signs in to complete the authentication. You can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#user_accounts) for different scenarios when you may want to use **user-centric flow**.

Nonetheless, one of the recommended approaches by Google when using Google Cloud's APIs like Cloud Storage, is to utilize **Client library authentication**. As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#libauth):

> Client libraries can use Application Default Credentials to easily authenticate with Google APIs and send requests to those APIs.

Client libraries are a good approach if you are doing testing or simply would like to know more about a Google's Cloud APIs.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) you will find more information on how to begin working with the **Cloud Storage's Client Library**.

Finally, I attached how Google Cloud thinks about [authentication strategies](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#authentication_strategies) when building an application using the Google Cloud APIs, but you could follow these general steps:

1. Choose and use the provided Cloud Client Libraries.
2. Determine the correct authentication flow for your application.
3. Find or create the application credentials needed for your application.
4. Pass the application credentials to the client libraries at application startup time, ideally through Application Default Credentials (ADC)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is some simple testing code that I used to download a blob

[Buckets: get API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get):

```
    import google.auth
    import google.auth.transport.requests

    creds, projects = google.auth.default()
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    creds.refresh(auth_req)

    print(creds.token)


    bucket = 'test'
    file = 'file'

    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/{}/o/{}?alt=media'.format(bucket, file)
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(creds.token), 'Accept': 'application/json'}

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    print(r.text)
    #The content of your file
```